# Passar $_SESSION em load() jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, load

Gostaria de saber se é possível passar um `$_SESSION` por `load()` do jquery.

Tenho uma página, onde chamo por load outra, mas preciso pegar o valor de `$_SESSION` na segunda página, mas não está funcionando, daí minha dúvida é essa, será que é possível passar `$_SESSION` por `load()`, pois por `$.post()` deu certo.

**PÁGINA 1:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = 1;
?>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#retorno").load("pagina1.php");
})
```

**PÁGINA 2:**

```
<?php
    session_start();

?>
<div class="teste">
    <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>
</div>
```

Eu fiz algo parecido em meu script e não funcionou, todos os arquivos estão em `UTF-8 sem BOM`.

> Possível é, utilizei o plugin `EditThisCookie`, e pude verificar o
>   erro, em uma determinada página ele criava o cookie da sessão com um nome
>   diferente, daí quando chamava no outro lado não conseguia pegar a sessão, pois o cookie estava com outro nome.

Comment: abcd se está a usar sempre PHP, a global `$_SESSION` está sempre presente enquanto estiver logado.

Comment: Realmente, em uma determinada página ele criava um nome para a SESSÃO, daí qunado chamava a sessão não reconhecia, pois criava um novo cookie...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se as paginas estiverem no mesmo domínio coloque `load` ele também funciona e eu fiz um teste local aqui e esta ok.